# How to combine LINQ contains query with count on all records and retrieve records with offset

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have page with pagination and search on movies, the movies table has 388262 records. Without using search the below code works fast. But when using search (vm.Search is filled) it becomes slow to retrieve the records.

So basically it's doing the contains/like query two times, one for returning the results with the offset and one for the count without the offset, this is correct, but is there a way to combine this for improved performance?

The weird thing is, when I use the queries from the log and execute them directly on the database using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). It executes the two queries rather fast in around 2 seconds. While it takes around 10 seconds when it's executed with the code/linq?

The code where I do the LINQ:

```c#
public IActionResult Index(MovieIndexViewModel vm) {
    IQueryable<Movie> query = _movieRepository.GetQueryable().AsNoTracking()
        .Select(m => new Movie {
            movie_id = m.movie_id,
            title = m.title,
            description = m.description
        });

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Search)) {
        query = query.Where(m => m.title.Contains(vm.Search));
    }

    vm.Movies = query.Skip(_pageSize * (vm.Page - 1)).Take(_pageSize).ToList();
    vm.PageSize = _pageSize;
    vm.TotalItemCount = query.Count();
    return View(vm);
}
```

SQL log from the the line with Skip and Take:

```sql
SELECT [m].[movie_id], [m].[title], [m].[description]
FROM [Movie] AS [m]
WHERE [m].[title] LIKE ('%' + @__vm_Search_0) + '%'
ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY
```

SQL log from the line with Count:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Movie] AS [m]
WHERE [m].[title] LIKE ('%' + @__vm_Search_0) + '%'
```

Comment: Sounds like your problem has nothing to do with what you are asking. You have a performance problem in EF. You should fix that. Try clearing your query cache.

Comment: I wonder why you have to call `_movieRepository.GetQueryable()`. This seens redudant unless your _movieRepository isn't already an `IQueryable<T>`. Can you post it's definition? If it's an `IEnumerable<T>` then that's your problem: It happens in memory on the whole dataset

Comment: @Tseng _movieRepository is a repository from the repository pattern. GetQueryable is a own function I made that returns an IQueryable for Movie entities. When I worked this function more out it will get its own function in movieRepository. Instead of putting this logics directly in my controller.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will run both queries concurrently. However this code will only perform ~[latency to SQL server] faster, which should be in the order of 10ms.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(MovieIndexViewModel vm) {
    IQueryable<Movie> query = _movieRepository.GetQueryable().AsNoTracking()
        .Select(m => new Movie {
            movie_id = m.movie_id,
            title = m.title,
            description = m.description
        });

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vm.Search)) {
        query = query.Where(m => m.title.Contains(vm.Search));
    }
    var moviesTask = query.Skip(_pageSize * (vm.Page - 1)).Take(_pageSize).ToListAsync();
    var countTask = query.CountAsync();
    vm.Movies = await moviesTask;
    vm.PageSize = _pageSize;
    vm.TotalItemCount = await countTask;
    return View(vm);
}
```

I suspect you aren't looking for a 10ms performance tweak. Instead, focus on the query plan.

Things you should try.

1. Add `.OrderBy(m => m.title)` into `query`
2. Add more indices
3. Clear the query cache

Things to check

1. Are you accurately benchmarking? Is that 8 seconds of JITer followed by 2 seconds of actual run?
2. Any weird HTTP systems like proxies in the way?
3. DNS?
4. Are you running in release or debug mode?